# Web Audio API get byte stream of currently playing Audio

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-recording, web-audio-api

I have a couple of active AudioContext in my game that are being organized by the audio library Howler.js.
These AudioContext are playing audio from my game. Is it possible to besides playing the audio also record the bytestream of the currently playing audio? How would this look? I want to send this audio over webrtc to other clients.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Considering you have access to the Audio Contexts, these references should help you connect them directly to webRTC, through a mediaStream

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/webrtc-integration.html

See example 3, from the link above:

```
<script>
    navigator.getUserMedia('audio', gotAudio);
    function gotAudio(stream) {
        var microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
        var peer = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        microphone.connect(filter);
        filter.connect(peer);
        peerConnection.addStream(peer.stream);
    }
</script>
```

Here, the stream is taken from the microphone. You should get it from your audio contexts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But here the stream is supplied by the getUserMedia which returns a stream, then the stream is fed into a createMediaStreamSource(micStream), but how do I get that stream from an audio context? I have tried something like that with no success. If I can just get a stream or bytes from a running audio context.